# Multiple Airflow XCOMs

Tags: airflow

I am pushing multiple values to XCOM based on values returned from a database. As the number of values returned may vary, I am using the index as the key.

How do I, in the next task, retrieve all the values from the previous task. Currently I am only returning the last XCOM from t1 but would like all of them.

Comment: what do you mean by "the last XCOM"? are you running your task more than one time? can you please share example code, not your actual, just a simple example to reproduce the issue. are you pushing your values to XCOM in a list or with different keys?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for [xcom_pull](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1517).

You'll see it had some filter logic and defaulting behaviour. I believe you are doing `xcom_pull()[-1]` or equivalent. But you can use `task_ids` argument to provide a list in order of the explicit task_ids that you want to pull xcom data from. Alternatively, you can use the keys that you push the data up with.

So in your case, where you want all the data emitted from the last `task_instance` and that alone, you just need to pass the `task_id` of the relevant `task` to the `xcom_pull` method.